# d3.js mouse over one node to trigger another node's mouse over event

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I attempt to combine sunburst with edges.

Here is what I have done right now: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~yongnan/untitled/ringLevel.html
[image]

when you mouseover on the red dots it will highlight related links.

In the program, dots has bind mouse over event.

Also the arc of the sunburst also bind the mouseover enent,

I want to mouse over the arc, then trigger the mouse over event on the node, how can I accomplish?

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.